# empty ruby variable, but when running says its not empty

Tags: ruby

ok im trying to set an empty variable in ruby

my code looks like this:

```
name = ""

if !name
    puts "name is empty"
else
    puts "name is not empty"
end
```

after I do the typical : ruby test.rb

it says : **name is not empty** . but **name = ""**
is empty :/

I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: `if` check for non-`false` and non-`nil`

Comment: think of it this way: what is the "logical not" of an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`""` is true in a boolean context

`nil` and `false` are the only falsey values in Ruby.

You could do

```
if name.empty?
    puts "name is empty"
else
    puts "name is not empty"
end
```

or

```
if name == ""
    puts "name is empty"
else
    puts "name is not empty"
end
```

Comment: Thanks man, I come from PHP where to do something like this you would need to write:

Comment: my pleasure sir :)

Comment: I was confused because in PHP you can do

Comment: <?php

$var = "";


if(!$var)
{
 echo 'is empty';
 
 

}else {
 echo 'is not empty';


}

?>

Comment: yeah, I know. every language has its rules about what's true and false.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = ""


if name.empty?
    puts "name is empty"
else
    puts "name is not empty"
end
```

Output

```
name is empty
```

You are trying to negate the string which would always be false.